# Upgrade failed from Plone 4.3.8 to 5.0.2 in Debian 8

Tags: migration, plone, upgrade, plone-5.x

I had a plone instance (4.3.6) with site "keti" and upgraded (copy Data.fs and blobtorage to the new instance) it successfully to 4.3.8.

Ps. There are many contents in Chinese in the site "keti".

But failed to upgrade it to 5.0.2.  This is the message in event.log: http://pastie.org/10773173.

(With activated add-ons: Diazo theme support and  Static resource storage,  I tried successfully for a empty site migration from 4.3.8 to 5.0.2)

Any suggestion?

Best regards.

Hugo

Comment: Can you say, which version of plone.app.upgrade you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed plone.app.intid in your addons? When not, do this. Clear your Catalog and Rebuild. I think the problem is in

```
register_all_content_for_intids
    obj = brain.getObject()
  File "/**/Products.ZCatalog-3.0.2-py2.7.egg/Products/ZCatalog/CatalogBrains.py", line 108, in getObject
    return parent.restrictedTraverse(path[-1])
  File "/**/Zope2-2.13.23-py2.7.egg/OFS/Traversable.py", line 317, in restrictedTraverse
    return self.unrestrictedTraverse(path, default, restricted=True)
  File "/**/Zope2-2.13.23-py2.7.egg/OFS/Traversable.py", line 300, in unrestrictedTraverse
    raise e
NotFound: 1306115487
```

It's only an Idea, not a solution.